# Does numpy check the data type and length when calling it? Where is the source code for the check?

Tags: numpy

Python

```
import numpy as np
class P(list):
    def __init__(self, achievement=[]):
        self.achievement = achievement
        self.extend(achievement)

    def __len__(self):
        print('___len___')
        print(self.achievement)
        return 2.0

    def __getitem__(self, idx): 
        return 1/0


j = P([1,2,3])

np.log(j)
```

this will raise an error

TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type PeopleList which has no callable log method

Comment: Can you clarify the question and what you are trying to achieve? Also, what are you referring to as "it" when you say "calling it"? Adding some context in the body of your question may be helpful.

Comment: `np.log` first does `np.array(j)`.  In your case that will be a 0d object dtype array (check that yourself).  When given object dtype arrays ufuncs try to apply a method to each element.  In this case it is trying to do `j.log()`, giving the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling log on this:

```
In [30]: np.log(j)
___len___
[1, 2, 3]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
AttributeError: 'P' object has no attribute 'log'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[30], line 1
----> 1 np.log(j)

TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type P which has no callable log method
```

It first tries to make an array:

```
In [31]: np.array(j)
___len___
[1, 2, 3]
Out[31]: array([1, 2, 3], dtype=object)
```

The shape of this array is `()`, one element.  That element is a `P` instance.

If we pass this object to `np.add`, it does a list add:

```
In [32]: np.add(j,j)
___len___
[1, 2, 3]
___len___
[1, 2, 3]
Out[32]: [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

In general math, with operators or `ufunc` on object dtype arrays is hit or miss.  If the elements support the right methods, it works; otherwise you get errors like this.

### edit

Changing the `len` result to int, 2

```
In [72]: j
___len___
[1, 2, 3]
Out[72]: [1, 2, 3]
```

Previously this `ipython` display, which uses the `repr`, was raising an error, complaining about some float.  Since the `print` (using `str`) worked, I ignored it.

```
In [73]: print(j)
[1, 2, 3]
```

Now making an array from this is just like making an array from a list.  The result is a numeric dtype, not the 0d object dtype as before:

```
In [74]: np.array(j)
___len___
[1, 2, 3]
Out[74]: array([1, 2, 3])
```

And the log works as expected:

```
In [75]: np.log(j)
___len___
[1, 2, 3]
Out[75]: array([0.        , 0.69314718, 1.09861229])
```

So yes, a float `len` is unexpected and problematic.

Comment: ```When I change the return 2.0 in __init__ to 2, it will not report an error```

Comment: `np.array(j)` now produces a normal numeric dtype array, and the log works.